# ElasticSearch NotFound after purging a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

I have a "live-test" environment for my rails application which lets us test our application with near-real production settings (email are sent for real, etc.)

I have added some buttons to this "live-test" website that lets us quickly purge a collection (ie. remove all documents from a MongoDB collection)

```
 def purge
    if Rails.env.production?
      should_not_happen(severity: :armageddon)
    else
      Company.unscoped do
        Company.all.each(&:destroy)
      end
      Utility.seed
      flashy(:info, 'company XXX restored')
      redirect_back
    end
  end
```

The problem rises with ElasticSearch. The first time this purge method is called, it works fine, I have some error

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotFound in MyController#purge
```

If I click refresh several times on my browser, after 2-3 times the request is finally accepted, but then I have the same problem again :

```
# 1st time executing purge action : Works
# 2nd time : [404] {"found":false,"_index":"professionals-test","_type":"employee","_id":"57221655f5ae457700b464a2","_version":4}
# 3rd time : [404] {"found":false,"_index":"professionals-test","_type":"employee","_id":"57221655f5ae457700b464a5","_version":6}
# 4th time : [404] {"found":false,"_index":"professionals-test","_type":"employee","_id":"57221655f5ae457700b464a7","_version":4}
# 5th Time : Works
# 6th refresh : Again errors....
```

I am using AWS ElasticSearch service with the classic elasticsearch ruby gems.